# Is the following structure with body and loc-args in the same notification payload valid?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Would the following payload notification cause any problems if you have body and loc-args and loc-key in the same payload?

```
{"aps":{"alert":{"body" : "Bob wants to play poker", "loc-key":"general","loc-args":["Test DEFAULT."]},"badge":1,"sound":"default"}}
```

The reason I have it set up like this. Is that I am not sure if the notification to just have a body in would be handle during the app, so it would use the localized loc-args in with the following key-valus in the localizable string:

```
"general"="%@";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to localize an alert message embedded in a push notification. One is to localize on the server and send the localized message as a string value of the `alert` key. Eg:

`{"alert": "A localized sentence."}`

Optionally, if you want to also set the launch image and/or have the view button of the alert read something other than 'View', you would replace the string value of `alert` with a dictionary. In this case the string value should be the value of `body` in the dictionary. Eg:

`{'alert': 
{'body: "A localized sentence.", action-loc-key: "...", launch-image: "..."'
}}`

The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9) warn that if you only have the `body` key in the dictionary, don't use a dictionary. Instead set the value of `body` as the string value of `alert`.

The other option is to use the `loc-key`, `loc-args` pair and have the localization take place on the device.

Although I have not verified which one iOS defaults to if both `body` and `loc-key` are present in the `alert` dictionary, I guess it will pick one and ignore the other. Someone with access to a working push notification dev setup could verify which one.

Ultimately, one can infer from the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9) that `body` and `loc-key` should be used in an exclusive or relationship. Either one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 6):

I've made several tests.

For example sending

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "body": "hello world!",
            "loc-args": ["andy", "my text"],
            "loc-key": "comment"
        }
    },
    "sound": "default",
    "extras": {}
}
```

On my device I have a string in the loc file that looks like:

```
"comment" = "%@ has comment %@";
```

So the notification that I'm receiving is:

```
Andy has comment my text
```

Now I've sent a new notification like this:

```
    {
        "aps": {
            "alert": {
                "body": "hello world!",
                "loc-args": ["andy", "my text"],
                "loc-key": "does_not_exist"
            }
        },
        "sound": "default",
        "extras": {}
    }
```

with a loc-key that does not exist, and the notification that I'm receiving is

```
does_not_exist
```

so as kadam said in his answer:

> Ultimately, one can infer from the docs that body and loc-key should
>   be used in an exclusive or relationship. Either one or the other, but
>   not both.
>
> Blockquote

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16057160/5021766), if the key is missing the key is used. That's why 'body' is always ignored and is EITHER ONE or the OTHER.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 50 yet so I can't comment but to follow-up on @kadam answer, just for future reference to those who will visit this question.

> Although I have not verified which one iOS defaults to if both body and loc-key are present in the  alert dictionary, I guess it will pick one and ignore the other. Someone with access to a working push notification dev setup could verify which one.

I have tried it and it defaults to the value of loc-key if it has a value on the app itself. If none then it uses the value of body.

Comment: You should add this as a comment to @kadam's answer, not post it as its own answer.